# Extracting image from <description> RSS feed with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rss

I'm trying to learn AngularJS while building a simple RSS feed. I managed to make a JSON request and retrieve all the data, title, link, description and all of the RSS I parse. I extract the images like this:

```
angular.forEach(feed.entries, function(value){
        value.myImage = $(value.content).find('img').eq(0).attr('src');
        console.log('image' + value.myImage);
}
```

However, there are some feeds that have different structure and instead placing the images inside `<content> </content>` like [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/popular.rss), the image is placed inside `<description> </description>` like [this one](https://www.behance.net/feeds/projects) and I'm trying to get it this way:

```
angular.forEach(feed.entries, function(value){
    value.myImage = $(value.description).find('img').eq(0).attr('src');
    console.log('no image' + " " + value.myImage);
});
```

But all I get is undefined, so I can not display the image from this feed. I tried different methods but I'm really lost and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I've been googling around and trying this for weeks. Any help is super appreciated!

Thanks :)

---

Here is the JSON object I'm getting.

```
Object {feedUrl: "https://www.behance.net/rss", title: "Behance Featured Projects", link: "http://www.behance.net", author: "", description: "The latest projects featured on the Behance"…}
$$hashKey: "027"
author: ""
description: "The latest projects featured on the Behance"
entries: Array[10]
0: Object
$$hashKey: "029"
author: ""
categories: Array[0]
content: "<img src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/404/2e322a33145177.Y3JvcCw4NzYsNjg0LDAsNzc.jpg" style="float:left;margin-right:15px"><br> Various Illustrations by Patryk Hardziej / 2015"
contentSnippet: " Various Illustrations by Patryk Hardziej / 2015"
link: "https://www.behance.net/gallery/33145177/Various-Illustrations-2015"
publishedDate: "Thu, 28 Jan 2016 08:00:02 -0800"
sImage: undefined
title: "Various Illustrations 2015"
```

Comment: In your example, you didn't affect $(value.description).find('img').eq(0).attr('src'); to value.sImage variable. Maybe it is just that :)

Comment: value.sImage = $(value.description).find('img').eq(0).attr('src');

Comment: @YoannProt thank you, just didn't copy that line properly, but it is not that! I modified the code :D

Comment: Can you add an example of the JSON you received ?

Comment: @YoannProt I added it on the post.

Comment: What the value of console.log(value.description). I didn't see a description with <img> in your JSON example.

Comment: https://www.behance.net/feeds/projects here is the feed where i am getting the JSON object. As you see, the <img> is inside <description>. When I get the object is true that the structure is different. Byt try what i try, i always end with undefined if the img is inside description. 

 console.log(value.description) is also undefined..

So, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add your $http request ? and how do you convert xml to json ? In any case, if value.description is undefined, that means your json object is not what you expected

Comment: here is my request, i do it via $resource:

`.factory('FeedLoader', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load', {}, {
      fetch: { method: 'JSONP', params: {v:'1.0', callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'} }
    });


});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I find it :)

The HTML you got from query looks like

```
<img src="..."> Some text <br/> Some text ...
```

The find method only works to find child node. In this case, img is not a child of value.content so it return nothing.

You can do

```
angular.forEach(feed.entries, function(value){
  // force creation of a root node -> find method should works for all cases
  var content = '<div>'+value.content+'</div>';
  value.myImage = $(content).find('img').eq(0).attr('src');
  console.log('image' + value.myImage);
}
```

Comment: Yes man! You got it :D Thank you very much, your help is super appreciated !